# html5/jquery mobile - Reverse Geocoding issue

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page that gets your current Longitude/Latitude location and when you submit it, it goes to a page that displays it on Google Maps with a marker. If you click on it, a balloon pops up with a static string:

(I'm currently having it display the lat/lng values)

```
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: '<p>' + lat + ',' + lng + '</p>'
  });
```

So I have the values, but when I try and run the `latlng` variable through `geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}...` it just breaks and doesn't display anything but the map. Also, it doesn't automatically get the current location on the landing page.

You can see it here:
[code example](http://jessemorgan.me/mobile)

This is my first attempt at geocoding, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I was using this page as a reference:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
var lat = $("#lat").val();
var lng = $("#lng").val();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );
```

You are fetching the values of two text fields into the `lat` and `lng` variables, but those are *strings*. You need them to be numbers instead. An easy way to convert them is with the unary `+` operator:

```
var lat = +$("#lat").val();
var lng = +$("#lng").val();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );
```

With that change, your map works as expected.

Comment: Aaaah ok. I didn't realize it was a string/integer problem. Thank you!

Comment: It's a very common error - I've done it myself. That's why it was easy to spot! :-) It's unfortunate that the Maps API doesn't do any error checking or conversion of the `LatLng` arguments.

Comment: Yeah, you'd think since it's Google and all, they'd account for things like that lol   Hey, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Michael's answer is correct, however I prefer to use [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) which is specifically for converting a string like `"1.234"` into a floating point Number like `1.234`

```
var lat = parseFloat($("#lat").val());
var lng = parseFloat($("#lng").val());
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );
```